# Django and Chart.js: Line-Chart with multiple Datasets

Tags: javascript, python, django, dataset, chart.js

I'm trying to create a Line-Chart with chart.js and multiple datasets (the amount of datasets can change during it's lifetime):

...from my "views.py":

```
label = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
coworker = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Michael Smith']
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1, 5]]
```

If this would be a line chart with only one list of data and just one coworker, my chart usually looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: {{ label|safe }},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Some text...',
                data: {{ data|safe }},
                backgroundColor: ...,
                borderColor: ...,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }],
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I already tried to loop through my datas like this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: {{ label|safe }},
            datasets: [{
                label: [{% for i in label%}"{{ i }}",{% endfor %}],
                data: [{% for j in data %}{{ j }}, {% endfor %}],,
                backgroundColor: ...,
                borderColor: ...,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }],
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Right now the chart and the labels from "Monday" to "Friday" are visible, but that's about it...
Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong or even got a better solution?

Thanks and a nice day!

Comment: I have same situation, did you find any solution for dynamic number of dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 3 different datasets out of your available data.

This is illustrated in below runnable code snippet. Unfortunately I don't know much about python. Therefore this is a pure JavaScript solution. I however think that you'll be able to easily include your python code in order to obtain the same result.

```js
const label = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
const coworker = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Michael Smith'];
const data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1, 5]];

var myChart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [{
      label: coworker[0],
      data: data[0],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: coworker[1],
      data: data[2],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: coworker[2],
      data: data[2],
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My only problem is, the amount of datasets has to be changeable and compatible with Django. Still, thank you for this solution!